# Dynamic removal border in tags <ul> <li>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to draw the line, which will vary depending on the choice of the tag

. 
Look what i have now: [image]

Look what i need to do: [image]

My main problem is that I do not know how to remove the border dynamically with

:active.

Please help me with it. May be it is not only css and html? some javascript?

html code here:

```
  <div class="layout-vbox-panel-item padding-top" style="background: transparent;">
        <ul data-componentname="tabSet" data-role="tabset" class="k-reset k-tabset">
        <li class="k-tab k-active-tab" data-tabindex="0"><span class="k-item">Описание</span></li>
<li class="k-tab" data-tabindex="1"><span class="k-item">Обсуждение</span></li>
<li class="k-tab" data-tabindex="2"><span class="k-item">План</span></li>
<li class="k-tab" data-tabindex="3"><span class="k-item">Файлы</span></li>
<li class="k-tab" data-tabindex="4"><span class="k-item">История</span></li></ul>
    </div>
```

css for ul here:

```
   .k-tabset {
display: block;
list-style-type: none;
line-height: 1.5;
overflow: none;
font-family: arial;
padding: 0px 3px;
white-space: nowrap;
```

css for li here:

```
background-color: #F5F5F5;
border: 1px solid #C5C5C5;
border-bottom: 1px solid;
border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
color: rgb(192,192,192);
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-weight: bolder;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 -1px 0 0;
position: relative;
```

for li:active

```
background-color: #fff;
z-index: 1;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
```

Comment: set border:none in css for li:active

Answer (score 1):

set

```
border:none
```

in css for `li:active`

Comment: doesnt work, because border:none removes all borders. I need only border-bottom:none
But, in what tag i have to make border? i think in div?

Comment: div is for all, you should give border-bottom:none to <li>. if you write li:active, this mean li tag

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 li:active
{
 background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  border:none;//removed your border-bottom
}
```

Comment: doesnt work, because border:none removes all borders. I need only border-bottom:none But, in what tag i have to make border? i think in div?

Comment: in the li tag give bordr and li:active tag set border-bottom:none

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EXZax/, if you are using js based tab navigation

```
$(function(){
    $('ul.k-tabset').on('click','li.k-tab',function(){
        $('ul.k-tabset').find('li.k-active-tab').removeClass('k-active-tab');
        $(this).addClass('k-active-tab');
    });

});
```

If your tabs are reloading the page. Use this

```
li.k-active-tab{
background-color: #fff;
z-index: 1;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```